# How does it work: Rectified Linear Unit in A Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

Can anybody tell me how the abovementioned algorithm works. Theoretically   I get it but I need some demonstration. A simple 2x2 matrix will do. Hope you can help me on this. This is  in relation to a Deep Learning course I am taking.

Answer (score 1):

The ReLU is simply a function:

f(x)=max(0,x)

So if you have a matrix:

X=[[0, 3],[-2,7]] ----> f(X) = [[0,3][0,7]]

During the backward pass, the gradient will flow only through the positive elements of the input matrix. The gradient mask obtained for the previous example would be:

X=[[0, 3],[-2,7]] ----> df(X)/d(X)=[[0,1][0,1]]

Since the derivative of ReLU is not defined for x=0, another valid mask could have been:

df(X)/dX=[[c,1][0,1]] with c between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

The RELU formula is simply `f(x)=max(0,x)` so it basically put to zero all negative numbers in the convolution matrix.

[Here](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/08/brohrer-convolutional-neural-networks-explanation.html/2) you have a good explanation of the RELU and Convolutional Neural Nets.